# Elevator standby + moving passanger , electricity consumption changes

Tags: energy, electrical

I'm interested specific on electricity consumption changes on 2 different situations inside an elevator.

1. When the elevator is stopped and people enters the elevator, does it change in any way the electricity consumption? Simple logic tells as that the elevator in this state is stopped by brakes, and brakes pressure is not affected by the amount of people being inside the elevator, so there should be no difference on electricity consumption on this case.
2. If elevator is going up/down, and a passenger is walking, jumping inside the elevator does this makes any difference on power consumption of the elevator? or regarding the external motor we can see all the cabinet as a unit and the forces that interact inside the cabinet doesn't change anything regarding the external force that is trying to make all the cabinet move ? If it's true how is called this principle?

Comment: Forget simple logic:  look up **how** an elevator works.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft do you have a source of complete explanation of mechanics of an elevator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When power fails the elevator must remain safe, which means the brakes will be released by applying power.
2. The force required to move the cabin will change according to how the passenger is accelerating himself. Similar how a phone can vibrate all on its own by oscillating a mass inside of it. The mean power required to lift the cabin+passenger will remain the same regardless of what he's doing in there.

Comment: regarding 1. not sure what you mean that breaks will be released by applying power?, if breaks are releases it should cause elevator to go down.  My question was originally related to the state where doors are open and somebody is entering the elevator. There is any additional electric energy used to maintain the elevator in place?

Comment: Regarding 2. I think I'm clear on your answer, so if somebody jumps we can have temporary effects on how much force the elevator uses to lift the passengers, but what about walking? does the walking have any effect on the up/down forces being applied?

Comment: @ABens In 1 I mean there is a spring holding the brake applied, then power is applied to the actuator to release it. The cabin is held in tracks so walking side to side won't have any appreciable effect.